# Error calling FileHold API DocumentFinder.LoadSmartFolder, "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized."

Tags: web-services, powershell, session-cookies

I am trying to do a search in FileHold with the dot net API from Powershell. The script can login okay, but then I get this error that implies I am not authorized.

```
Exception calling "LoadSmartFolder" with "1" argument(s): "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized."
At line:8 char:57
+ $searchCriteria = $lmDocumentFinderProxy.LoadSmartFolder <<<< ( $savedSearchId )
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Here is some sample code that demonstrates the issue.

```
$userId = "sysadm"
$password = "12345"
$clientType = "CustomClient"
$savedSearchId =  6

$urmSessionManagerProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri http://fileholdtest4/fh/filehold/UserRoleManager/SessionManager.asmx?WSDL
$sessionId = $urmSessionManagerProxy.StartSession( $userId, $password, $clientType )

$lmDocumentFinderProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri http://fileholdtest4/fh/filehold/LibraryManager/DocumentFinder.asmx?WSDL                
$searchCriteria = $lmDocumentFinderProxy.LoadSmartFolder( $savedSearchId )
$prevGuid = [guid]::empty
$guid = [guid]::empty
$columns = $lmDocumentFinderProxy.GetDocumentsBySnapshot( $prevGuid, [ref]$guid, "SRT", $searchCriteria, $null, 0, 20 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no cookie passed to the `DocumentFinder` service with a valid session id. The `StartSession` method for the `SessionManager` service is one of the few FileHold services that does not require a valid session identified by a cookie. That is why it is working without the cookie.

A session id is provided with a successful `StartSession` call. You need to create a cookie container and add a `FHLSID` cookie and attach it to the `DocumentFinder` proxy.

The following code illustrates the necessary changes for the example.

```
$userId = "sysadm"
$password = "12345"
$clientType = "CustomClient"
$savedSearchId =  6

$urmSessionManagerProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri http://fileholdtest4/fh/filehold/UserRoleManager/SessionManager.asmx?WSDL
$sessionId = $urmSessionManagerProxy.StartSession( $userId, $password, $clientType )

$lmDocumentFinderProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri http://fileholdtest4/fh/filehold/LibraryManager/DocumentFinder.asmx?WSDL                

$uri = [System.Uri]$lmDocumentFinderProxy.Url
$cookie = New-Object System.Net.Cookie( "FHLSID", $sessionId, "/", $uri.Host ) 
$lmDocumentFinderProxy.CookieContainer = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer
$lmDocumentFinderProxy.CookieContainer.Add( $cookie )                

$searchCriteria = $lmDocumentFinderProxy.LoadSmartFolder( $savedSearchId )
$prevGuid = [guid]::empty
$guid = [guid]::empty
$columns = $lmDocumentFinderProxy.GetDocumentsBySnapshot( $prevGuid, [ref]$guid, "SRT", $searchCriteria, $null, 0, 20 )
```